# Remove listener in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'd added a listener in following code to a game object :

```
 Game_Controller.Database [m, n].Nute_M.AddComponent(typeof(EventTrigger));
 EventTrigger trigger =Game_Controller.Database [m, n].Nute_M.GetComponent<EventTrigger> ();
 EventTrigger.Entry entry = new EventTrigger.Entry ();
 entry.eventID =EventTriggerType.PointerClick;
 entry.callback.AddListener ((eventData) => Game_Controller.Database [m, n].Nute_M.GetComponent<Nute_Onclick> ().onclick (m, n, "white"));
 trigger.triggers.Add (entry);
```

I have a problem in Removing this listener from game object ....

it doesn't work:

```
EventTrigger trigger =Game_Controller.Database [indexi, indexj].Nute_M.GetComponent<EventTrigger> ();
EventTrigger.Entry entry = new EventTrigger.Entry ();
entry.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerClick;
entry.callback.RemoveAllListeners ();
trigger.triggers.Add (entry);
```

please help me.

Comment: @Fatemeh Abdollahei Thanks Fateme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need remove listener for same object as you add. In line `trigger.triggers.Add (entry);` you add instance of `EventTrigger.Entry` to list. When you use `EventTrigger.Entry entry = new EventTrigger.Entry ();` you create new inctsnce of EventTrigger.Entry that not have any listeners in `triggers` list. So you must find entry you created earler in list, and remove listener from it.
Example:

```
EventTrigger trigger =Game_Controller.Database [indexi, indexj].Nute_M.GetComponent<EventTrigger> ();
List<EventTrigger.Entry> entriesToRemove = new List<EventTrigger.Entry>();

//finding required entry by eventId
foreach (var entry in trigger.triggers)
{        
    if (entry.eventID == EventTriggerType.PointerClick)
    {
        //remove listener from entry
        entry.callback.RemoveAllListeners();
        //add entry to transitional list
        entriesToRemove.Add(entry);
    }
}

//remove all entries satisfied condition from triggerlist
foreach(var entry in entriesToRemove)
{
    trigger.triggers.Remove(entry);
}
```

Comment: Hi Mr.Sergiy Klimkov ......how are u ?   I use your code in my project.....but get error Use of unassigned local variable `entry'  for 'entry.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerClick' line ....please help

Comment: hi sergiy klimkov are u ok?  my brother  after use your edited answer i get error   ' The name `entriesToRemove' does not exist in the current context' ...... please help me  my brother

Comment: Oh. You nned initalize the list. Check the new edition.

Comment: My brother, give me a book explaining all these tips thoroughly so that I can read it in professional gaming.Please introduce me a book.

Comment: It is not relevant especially a game developing. It more relative to OOP. So you need to understand relations between objects. 

You will try to google object oriented programming with c#.